# Facebook API call works in browser, but not in code

Tags: php, http, facebook-graph-api

I am working on a Facebook application and I have a script that sends notifications to users whenever an important event has occurred. This script goes through a list of users and fires off notifications in a loop. Now, when I activate the script, nothing happens, and I get the following error in my log concerning the url's that I tried to access:

```
 failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\n
```

However, when I copy and paste a supposedly bad url into the browser, I get a message of success and the notification appears on Facebook. My question here is, is there any reason the url would not be accepted from a pHP program, but only from browser access?

Here is a code snippet:

```
$apprequest_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/".
$user_id.
"/notifications?href=apps.facebook.com/vmoodletest".
"&template='sigh'&".
$app_access_token."&method=post";

$result = file_get_contents($apprequest_url);
```

Here is the resulting url:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/xxxxxxxxxxxx/notifications?href=apps.facebook.com/vmoodletest&template='blah blah posted a comment on Does it work? in the -General Forum- forum in Senior Project.'&access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxx|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&method=post
```

Comment: is it possible to see what the apprequest_url looks that's being passed to file_get_contents (with your app_access_token redacted, of course)

Comment: Please use the PHP SDK instead of doing requests “manually” with file_get_contents. Its way more error-prone and easier to debug.

Comment: "Its way more error-prone and easier to debug" I'm not sure if you were bashing it or promoting it, but it worked. Thanks.